# Как выдернуть URL из img тега

Tags: php, wordpress, dom

вот такой вид img тега

```
<img alt="" data-src="https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-kToI3Byrrws/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAbmc/SVx6BR6wu3g/photo.jpg?sz=200" class="avatar avatar-wordpress-social-login avatar-32 photo" height="32" width="32">
```

нужно выдернуть url картинги без применения библиотек для парсинга. как это сделать?

я получаю так, но у меня что-то не растет:

```
<?php 
            $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
            $img = get_avatar( $current_user->ID, 32 ); 
 preg_match_all('/(data-src)=("[^"]*")/i',$img, $result);

$avabg = $result[2][0];
echo $avabg;?>
```

выдает мне такой результат

```
"https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-kToI3Byrrws/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAbmc/SVx6BR6wu3g/photo.jpg?sz=200"
```

а мне надо url без скобок и кавычек, для того что бы поставить его в css

браузер корректно не отображает
[image: не отобража5т]

Comment: на php? js? регулярками?

Comment: Пожалуйста дополните вопрос, как вы получает Dom чем вы хотите его парсить? и другие немаловажные ньюансы

Comment: 1)какие скобочки? 2)в css нужны кавычки https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/url#Examples

Comment: добавил @thisman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я верно протелепатировал ситуацию, то вы используете  wordpress  и тогда задача сводиться к использованию функции   **[get_avatar_url( $id );](https://wp-kama.ru/function/get_avatar_url)**

**с помощью регулярных выражений**

```
    preg_match('/< *img[^>]*src *= *["\']?([^"\']*)/i',  $img, $matches);
// $matches -будет содержать массив совпадений
```

или даже так как у вас

```
preg_match_all('/(data-src)=("[^"]*")/i',$img, $result);
$avabg = $result[2][0];
$rt=str_replace('"','',$avabg); // очистка от кавычек
```

Comment: get avatar url показывает стандартный аватар, мне нужно выдернуть имено из html тега

Comment: стоит плагин wp social login. и get avatar url никак не работает

Comment: а в чем разница? если у вас присвоен аватар пользователю, то get_avatar и вернет тоже самое что и get_avatar_url, с той лишь разницей что он обернет это в тег

Comment: вот сайт, в моб версии в меню должна быть аватарка https://mycrimea.online/

Comment: в том и дело, что get avatar url возражает адрес стандартной аватарки wordpress

Comment: результат wp get avatar url https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/5480fb675d02f32f5d335452b01027a4?s=96&d=mm&r=g

Comment: да да, я вас понял  плагин  тянет аватарки из апи социальных сетей

Comment: результат wp get avatar https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-kToI3Byrrws/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAbmc/SVx6BR6wu3g/photo.jpg?sz=200

Comment: дополнил ответ регулярным выражением